# How to define out of class functions for a class specialized using std::enable_if

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, generic-programming, partial-specialization

I have a specialization of a class called graph which is enabled only if the input is a particular type. I am not able to define out of class definitions for the functions inside that class. *This question os different from some other questions on stack overflow where sfinae happens on member function. Here I want enable if on the class and just define a normal member function for this class outside the class.*

Note- There are multiple graph classes with different container types. This is an example of just one.

I want to be able to define graph_func outside this class

```
template<typename ContainerType,
    std::enable_if<std::is_same<ContainerType, Eigen::MatrixXd>::value, int>::type = 0>
class graph
{
    .
    .
    .
    void graph_func() const;
}
```

I tried this and I get the error that it doesn't refer into any class

```
template <typename ContainerType>
void graph<ContainerType,  std::enable_if<std::is_same<Graph, Eigen::MatrixXd>::value, int>::type>::graph_func() const
{
  // definition
}
```

Comment: You could simplify your specialization definition to `template <> class graph<Eigen::MatriXd>`, there's no reason to use SFINAE. If you want to restrict `ContainerType` to be `Eigen::MatrixXd`, then use `static_assert`, or don't use a template at all

Comment: I have to use SFINAE because I have multiple graph class specializations for different container types. I don't think I can use static assert since that would occur after class selection and would eliminate the other specializations from selection.

Comment: That should be included in the question itself, as together with the code you wrote it all makes it unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that `std::enable_if<..., int>::type` in your parameter list is an [non-type template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters):

```
template<typename ContainerType,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<ContainerType, Eigen::MatrixXd>::value, int>::type = 0>
class graph
{
    void graph_func() const;
};
```

You need to pass the *value* of that type (In here we just named it `_`) to the parameter list:

```
template <typename ContainerType,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<ContainerType, Eigen::MatrixXd>::value, int>::type _>
void graph<ContainerType, _>::graph_func() const
{
  // definition
}
```

See [live demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/D4wZTs)